# Sorting based on 2 key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, arrayobject

I have an array of objects, each consisting of a nested array. I need to filter the main array based on an ID within the nested arrays. Objects with duplicate ID should be removed from the result.

The array of objects have nested arrays where there are 2 parameters: `"AuN": "sanjay mittal"` and the corresponding `"AuId"`. I need to make my main array object unique, based on the value for `"AuId"` that comes with `"AuN": "sanjay mittal"`

**Data :**

```
[
    {
        "CC": 623,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "tayfun e tezduyar",
                "AuId": 166714465
            },
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2141608163
            }
        ],
        "PK": 2009478656
    },
     {
        "CC": 488,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "tayfun e tezduyar",
                "AuId": 166714465
            },
            {
                "AuN": "marek behr",
                "AuId": 2117578800
            },
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",   
                "AuId": 2141608163        // duplicate data. Need to remove the main object
            }
        ],
        "PK": 1973948837
    },
    {
        "CC": 118,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "rajendra k premchand",
                "AuId": 1987062001
            },
            {
                "AuN": "kamal sharma",
                "AuId": 2426730634
            },
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2583035735
            },
            {
                "AuN": "inder s anand",
                "AuId": 1907699963
            }
        ],
        "PK": 2116095873
    },
    {
        "CC": 401,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2123420744
            },
            {
                "AuN": "brian falkenhainer",
                "AuId": 68193438
            }
        ],
        "PK": 153230822
    },
    {
        "CC": 86,
        "AA": [
           {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2123420744
            },
            {
                "AuN": "shulian shang",
                "AuId": 2723036630
            },
            {
                "AuN": "todd j mortier",
                "AuId": 2063047595
            },
            {
                "AuN": "cyril j schweich",
                "AuId": 2132794328
            }
        ],
        "PK": 2021819698
    }
]
```

**Expected result :**

My expected result removes some of the main objects, based on name `"AuN": "sanjay mittal"` and unique `"AuId"`:

```
var expectedArray = [
    {
        "CC": 623,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "tayfun e tezduyar",
                "AuId": 166714465
            },
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2141608163
            }
        ],
        "PK": 2009478656
    },
    {
        "CC": 118,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "rajendra k premchand",
                "AuId": 1987062001
            },
            {
                "AuN": "kamal sharma",
                "AuId": 2426730634
            },
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2583035735
            }
            {
                "AuN": "inder s anand",
                "AuId": 1907699963
            }
        ],
        "PK": 2116095873
    },
    {
        "CC": 401,
        "AA": [
            {
                "AuN": "sanjay mittal",
                "AuId": 2123420744
            },
            {
                "AuN": "brian falkenhainer",
                "AuId": 68193438
            }
        ],
        "PK": 153230822
    },
]
```

I am trying to find an efficient way to do this. Any insights and ways would help me achieve this.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Map` for this. Key it by the relevant AuId, and store the corresponding top level object for it. If you do this in reverse order, the first occurrence of the same AuId will survive in the map.

Then simply take those objects again from the map and you're done:

```js
const array = [{"CC":623,"AA":[{"AuN":"tayfun e tezduyar","AuId":166714465},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2141608163}],"PK":2009478656},{"CC":488,"AA":[{"AuN":"tayfun e tezduyar","AuId":166714465},{"AuN":"marek behr","AuId":2117578800},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2141608163}],"PK":1973948837},{"CC":118,"AA":[{"AuN":"rajendra k premchand","AuId":1987062001},{"AuN":"kamal sharma","AuId":2426730634},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2583035735},{"AuN":"inder s anand","AuId":1907699963}],"PK":2116095873},{"CC":401,"AA":[{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2123420744},{"AuN":"brian falkenhainer","AuId":68193438}],"PK":153230822},{"CC":86,"AA":[{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2123420744},{"AuN":"shulian shang","AuId":2723036630},{"AuN":"todd j mortier","AuId":2063047595},{"AuN":"cyril j schweich","AuId":2132794328}],"PK":2021819698}];

const map = new Map(array.reverse().map(obj => 
    [obj.AA.find(({AuN}) => AuN === "sanjay mittal").AuId, obj]
));
const filtered = Array.from(map.values()).reverse();
console.log(filtered);
```

This code assumes that each object has such a "sanjay mittal" entry. If this is not guaranteed, then you need to add some tests and decide what to do with such an "orphaned" object.

#### Addition:

In comments you mention you get an error about the *AuId* property. This means the assumption in the last paragraph above is not true. So here is how you could deal with such a situation:

```js
const array = [{"CC":623,"AA":[{"AuN":"tayfun e tezduyar","AuId":166714465},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2141608163}],"PK":2009478656},{"CC":488,"AA":[{"AuN":"tayfun e tezduyar","AuId":166714465},{"AuN":"marek behr","AuId":2117578800},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2141608163}],"PK":1973948837},{"CC":118,"AA":[{"AuN":"rajendra k premchand","AuId":1987062001},{"AuN":"kamal sharma","AuId":2426730634},{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2583035735},{"AuN":"inder s anand","AuId":1907699963}],"PK":2116095873},{"CC":401,"AA":[{"AuN":"s*a*n*jay mittal","AuId":2123420744},{"AuN":"brian falkenhainer","AuId":68193438}],"PK":153230822},{"CC":86,"AA":[{"AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId":2123420744},{"AuN":"shulian shang","AuId":2723036630},{"AuN":"todd j mortier","AuId":2063047595},{"AuN":"cyril j schweich","AuId":2132794328}],"PK":2021819698}];

const map = new Map(array.reverse().map((obj, i) => {
    const found = obj.AA.find(({AuN}) => AuN === "sanjay mittal");
    if (found) return [found, obj];
    return [-i, [...obj.AA, { "AuN":"sanjay mittal","AuId": "missing" }]];
}));
const filtered = Array.from(map.values()).reverse();
console.log(filtered);
```

This will detect the absence of the "sanjay mittal" entry, and will then consider the object is not a duplicate, and add entry "sanjay mittal"/"missing" to the filtered data.

Comment: Is there any other way around to accomplish this as there seems to be an issue while I am implementing this . I am getting undefined AuId and the response is same as mentioned above.

Comment: If the response is the same, then you must be doing something else than in my answer: when you run the snippet in my answer it works on that particular response. If you get undefined AuId it means that there is an entry in your input that does not have the "sanjay mittal" entry. If you want, I can update the code so that it will detect that situation and will present a more user friendly output.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: This only shows arrays of objects with authors name and adds missing sanjay mittal to results

Comment: Any other method to combat the same thing.As i have implemented this in my node js project.

Comment: Thanks trincot I was not handling the name for uppercase and lower case. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Ah I see. You got me confused there! ;-)